# CSS - make floating boxes stay on the "same line"

Tags: css-float, css

Consider the following fragment:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        #container {
            width: 400px;
            height: 600px;
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }

        .item {
            width: 50px;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="item">ITEM 1</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 2</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 3</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 4</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 5</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 6</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 7</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 8</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 9</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 10</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 11</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 12</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 13</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 14</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 15</div>
            <div class="item">ITEM 16</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It gives me the following result:

[image]

What I want is for all the inner boxes to stay on the same line *yet* the container having the width `400px` in case when the inner boxes don't fill it up completely, like this:

[image]

I'd really appreciate if someone hinted me on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: does your width have to be 50px for each item ?

Comment: if you want to specify the width where you want to overflow the items? same line means single line? is that right?

Comment: yes, exactly. I want the container box to *grow* if it doesn't fit its content, but not shrink.

Answer (score 0):

You could try working with display:table(-row)(-cell) instead of floating, see my answer to this question: [Force <DIV> to stay in one line with scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358910/force-div-to-stay-in-one-line-with-scroll-bar/8359850#8359850)

Important remark, however, is that this won't work in IE7...

Answer (score -1):

You can do a `white-space: nowrap` on the elements in the container that you don't want to wrap.

Demo here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: that won't do a thing, nowrap is for text only...